# NSFetchedResultsController controller didChange delegate - assertion failure

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, delegates, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I built a tableview, with FRC to show data from core-data. I also implemented the **controller didChange** delegate, to view the changes in the core-data:

```
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

        switch (type) {
        case .insert:
            if indexPath != nil && (indexPath?.row)! < (controller.fetchedObjects?.count)!{
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .left)
            }
            break;

        case .update:
            if indexPath != nil && (indexPath?.row)! < (controller.fetchedObjects?.count)!{
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .left)
            }
            break;

        case .delete:
            if indexPath != nil && (indexPath?.row)! < (controller.fetchedObjects?.count)!{
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .left)
            }
            break;

        case .move:
            if indexPath != nil && (indexPath?.row)! < (controller.fetchedObjects?.count)!{
                print("type.move: shouldn't get in here!")
            }
            break;

        }
    }
```

when I run I got this on the console:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section
>   after the update (216) must be equal to the number of rows contained
>   in that section before the update (215), plus or minus the number of
>   rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and
>   plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0
>   moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

although the app doesn't crash - but the tableview is screwed and doesn't show the date.

Comment: Seems you’ve updated the data (model) via the controller but you’ve not updating the view. I would be useful to see your code in the delegate method `controllerDidChangeContent` to help identify the issue.

Answer (score 3):

my mistake was that on **insert** and **update** I referred to *indexPath* instead of *newIndexPath*...

it should be:

```
        case .insert:
        if newIndexPath != nil && (newIndexPath?.row)! < (controller.fetchedObjects?.count)!{
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .left)
        }
        break;
```